# How to add a new base to the first commit of a git revision tree

Tags: git

I have setup a git repository for some days. Now I found my start point is some work based on an original release.
I hope to add the original release as the first commit and all the my current commit tree is based on it. Is it possible?
The current git revision:

A---B---C---D  master

I hope to insert one commit at the beginning

O---A---B---C---D  master, so that I could use rebase to generate such branch

O---A---B---C---D  master
\---D'  my_rebase_branch

Comment: Possibly you are looking for `git rebase --root`, but your question doesn't have enough details for me to know for sure.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting. I will draw a graph in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try it as below:
1. create a new branch called base_work for the original release branch
2. create a new branch called others_work for your start point
3. suppose your current work branch is my_work. Try the following command:

```
    git rebase --onto base_work others_work my_work
```

The command will let your work based on base_work, instead of others_work.

Comment: Where should the base_work branch off? I know the usage of rebase --onto. The current problem is that I don't have a commit containing the real origin.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to recreate your commits on top of existing commits of an existing repo, you would need to import that repo first before the rebase:

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git remote add original /url/original/repo
git fetch original
```

Then you can rebase, using the [`--root` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase---root):

```
git checkout master
git rebase --onto original/master --root master
```

If "`original`" does not exist, you can create it as long as you have access to the content (source code) of said release:

```
cd /path/to/original/source/code/of/release
git init .
git add .
git commit -m "original release source code"
```

Then, go back to your own repo, and repeat the command I mentioned (no need for `rebase --onto` here)

Comment: There is no existing repo in my case. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @ZhangLi I have edited my answer to take into account your comment.

Comment: VonC, Thank you very much. The final command should be git rebase --onto original/master --root master". Git is so flexible.